# How to identify if running a @DynamicUpdate in CompositeUserType

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a `org.hibernate.usertype.CompositeUserType` which refers to two columns in the database. I want to use

```
@DynamicUpdate
@OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.DIRTY)
```

for the entity using the `CompositeUserType` (it is also used elsewhere). Is there any way to identify inside the `CompositeUserType` if the query currently processed is a `@DynamicUpdate` or a normal one?

Reason for that: It seems that `CompositeUserType` doesn't work that well with `@DynamicUpdate`. Any experiences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. In Hibernate 6 we now model composite user types as embeddables which allow this though. Also see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddable-mapping-custom